# Open default app on windows 10 using bash shell

Tags: windows, bash, shell, git-bash

For some reason using *explorer* from command line does not yield the expected result when opening a nested folder or file:

```
explorer dir1/dir2/file
```

I found out, if all occurences of slashes are replaced by double black slashes then the command works out. So, I wrote this little shell script that would customize the desired input path:

```
_path="${1//\//\\\\}"
echo "explorer $_path"
explorer "$_path"
```

Unfortunately explorer opens the default *Documents* folder no matter which path I am providing, while the aimed behaviour is achieved, if I do copy the output by echo and paste it to the terminal...

My environment:

https://github.com/git-for-windows/git-sdk-64

```
$ uname
MSYS_NT-10.0-18363
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace *explorer* with *start* in the shell script